# Crystal Reports - formula to show date 6am - 6am (isntead of 12am - 12am)

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to write a formula that will display data date, but be offset to a 6am - 6am day, instead of a 12am - 12am day.

Therefor the concept would be something to this effect (but not sure how to write this in crystal):

if the time is 12:00am - 5:59am
then display data date minus 1 day
else display data date

anyone know how to make this happen?

much thanks.
JF

Comment: or is there a way to set the time zone to -6hours just for a certain field?

Comment: So for example 3:00am Jan 35, 9999 would change to 3:00am Jan 34, 9999?

Answer (score 1):

To subtract 6 hours from a certain field, you can create and use a formula field that contains the following code

```
DateAdd("h",-6,{TableName.FieldName})
```

for more information check this http://crystaltricks.com/wordpress/?p=153

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ShiftDateTime` function.  From CR's help:

The following example is applicable to both Basic and Crystal syntax:

`ShiftDateTime (DateTime (2000, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0), "EST,300,EDT", "PST,480,PDT")`

Returns 1/1/2000 9:00:00AM

In this example, noon Eastern Daylight Time is shifted to 9 am Pacific Daylight Time.